# Is wearing an insulated metal armor against a lightning safe?

Tags: electricity, lightning, insulators

Related: [Is wearing metal armor during lightning safe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206009/)  only partially answer my question.

During a discussion in my question in Worldbuilding, [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/88108/34288) explain that as long as the metal armor is wired to the ground, and insulated inside (for this Physic question using asbestos), wearing a metal armor should be fine when a lightning strike the armor.

However, another user in another question did some math and found that the person will not be safe because insufficient arc flash protection (whatever this means).

**Will the person within the armor still be fine (in sense is capable of, let's say, bar-fighting) after the lightning strike?**
What will happen to the person wearing the armor, if the armor is insulated by asbestos, and wired continuously to the ground?

Comment: He will die, in the  short term, of overheating, and in the long-term, of asbestosis. Seriously, how much energy is delivered is important to state, many golfers have survived, without armour obviously,  apologies if this is covered in the earlier answer. Arc flash is the heat produced, which the golfer can get away with, but which your warrior can't ignore.

Comment: Arc flash is best known as a hazard faced by electricians working on electric power distribution systems.  An accidental short circuit can cause an electric arc that is bright enough to cause third degree burns to somebody standing close by. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_flash

Comment: Why won't a Faraday cage work?  Any fine meshed screen worn by a designated person, *without* any insulation on the inside of it, would protect the wearer, because all of the charge would reside on the outside of the screen.

Comment: @DavidWhite on my question in worldbuilding, the lightning is shot by a lightning bender. According to the answer on another question, it won't work, for a reason I don't fully understand. I ask here to make sure that wearing armor, with or without insulation, will protect the user.

Comment: @DavidWhite only if the armour is electrically connected at all the joints with low resistance connections. I suspect most mediveal knights didn't  spec HCOFC copper straps between their Codpeice and Cuirass with unfortunate consequences

Comment: Try a thin suit of chain mail under the armor.

Comment: We might need some experimentalist to go Florida and play some medieval golf.

Comment: One can wonder how hot the armor might get.  Or, wear armor with a sharp spike on top of the helmet.  It might bleed off the induced ground charge before a lightning strike occurs (seems to work for my sail boat).  I've been told that you are safe in a hard topped car, but the tires may blow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be safe as long as your body is not grounded. That is how this person can play with lightning bolts in a Faraday suit.

[image]

Comment: Except those are'n't lightning bolts with 400,000 amps DC--there is no way it's safe. Plus grounding is irrelevant-- clouds aren't grounded--and then suddenly they are--what makes you think your rubber shoes are going to do anything?